# How to test an AWS API gateway that accepts form parameters sent in Http POST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, post, api-gateway

I am creating an API gateway in AWS that should accept a POST request from a form.

I want to test the API gateway as if it is receiving a POST request with form parameters. What I should add to the request body to conduct the test assuming that I have two form parameters "name" and "age"?

[image]

The web service accepts the parameters as @Formparams

Answer (score 0):

You can add a json body like this there.

```
{
   "name": "Test",
   "age": 25  

 }
```

Based on the target service the name could be different for the body.

For instance, if the target is a Lambda function based on Node.js, the body can be found in `event.body`.